# How to run Manual Gitlab job if variable value is correct?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, jobs, cicd

So I have the following job I created. I want the job to run only if the Value of VERSION is "TEST-INPUT". All other cases the job fails. How would I do this? So far, If I enter any value for VERSION in GITLAB, the job still runs.

```
test-manual-job:
  stage: test-stage
  when: manual
  variables:
    VERSION: "${VERSION}"
  rules:
  - if: '$VERSION == "TEST-INPUT"'
    allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "${VERSION} is the hard-coded input"
```

Comment: Do you want to run it manually or not? Are you asking how it can be run not-manually if it is a specific version?

Comment: I want to run it manually so if the user inputs TEST-INPUT as the value and clicks run job

Comment: I dont understand. You want to manually click "run job", but only run it if the user inputs TEST-INPUT? Why not just run it automatically if that input is there? Or verify that the value is there before manually running the job?

Answer (score 0):

`rules:` are only evaluated **when the pipeline is created**. When you are starting a manual **job**, specifying any variables will not affect whether the job runs or not because the `rules:` were evaluated at pipeline creation time.

> I want the job to run only if the Value of VERSION is "TEST-INPUT". All other cases the job fails.

Since you want to evaluate this condition after pipeline creation time, you can't use `rules:`. Instead, you can just add this logic to the job itself:

```yaml
myjob:
  when: manual
  before_script:
    - |
      if [[ "$VERSION" != "TEST-INPUT" ]]; then
          exit 1
      fi
  script:
    - echo "Version is ${VERSION}"
```